# Is there any way to download Mediafire links?

Tags: java, download, mediafire

I'm writing a program that reads in a text file of artists and albums, and spits out Mediafire download links.

I want to take it a step further and actually have it download those links, but I don't know if there's a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/) - it's an open source Java application that can download from many hosts, including Mediafire (I believe). You could either use it to download the links, or borrow their Mediafire code (assuming it is compatible with the licensing on your own application).